# FB Rate Limit Error 613. Based on accoutID or endpoint?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, rate-limiting

I got below 613 custom throttling rate limiting error in below.

```
{"error":{"message":"(#613) Calls to outcome prediction api have exceeded the rate of 4500 calls per 60 seconds.", "type":"OAuthException", "code":613,"fbtrace_id":"A5DNtRrGa7+"}}
```

And I would want to make it clear based on the sample request:
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/act_xxx/delivery_estimate?access_token=xxx

Is this mean the rate limiter is based on the limit exceed on endpoint (delivery_estimate here)? Or the given account? (act_xxx here)

Thanks!

Comment: I don't get the question ... if you can still make requests to other endpoints fine while you get this error for the one above, then that should answer that, no?

Comment: I just want to know this error indicates whether the actID got rate limited OR the endpoint got rate limited?